# X-Forwarded-For header not storing the real ip but has the nginx ip

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-ingress

I have a containerised application in which nginx is a reverse proxy. I am trying to forward the actual ip address of the user instead of the proxy ip address.

Below is part of my nginx file

the below part of inside the `http` block

```
  set_real_ip_from xxx.yyy.zz.xxx;
  real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
  real_ip_recursive on;

  server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    server_name _;

    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/index.html @app;
    }

    location @app {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
```

From what i understand the HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR should have the last non trusted ip address, but when i print the value of `request.env['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']` I still see that `xxx.yyy.zz.xxx` is also still part of `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` header value.

Is this the expected behaviour?

the `request.remote_ip` also holds the value `xxx.yyy.zz.xxx` which is the ip of the nginx proxy

Can anyone please help as to how can i forward the actual ip to the rails application instead of the nginx proxy.

Thanks.

Comment: what happens if you add the following to the *location @app* block: `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;`

Comment: hi @chuex, when i add it, the liveness and readiness probe fail

Comment: hi @chuex, sorry there was a typo from my end, when i set `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $http_x_forwarded_for;` the issue still remains

Comment: only just guessing - try removing the first three lines (real_ip related), and use the proxy_set_header line in my first comment.  If that doesn't work, I'm unsure what is wrong.  I only use x_forward_for in a non containerized app, and it works for me.

Comment: What's in the x_real_ip header according to your rails app?

Comment: @miknik, `request.env['X-Real-IP']` is blank

Comment: hi @chuex, when i remove the 3 lines and add `$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for`, the deployment does not complete as my liveness and readiness probe fail

Comment: @opensource-developer you should use `request.env['HTTP_X_REAL_IP']` to answer @miknik